# How to store a msg.payload into a script variable inside a ui_template node red?

Tags: javascript, templates, node-red

I wrote this code but it doesn't work

```
   <script type = "text/javascript">

        var msg = {{msg.payload}}

   </script>
```

this method consider the {{msg.payload}} value as an error due to the '{' in the syntax, I tried different ways, but nothing works, I guess I'm missing something that I don't understand, please I m open to any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dashboard UI node uses [Angular](https://angular.io/) for it's templating so you need do things a little differently.

A good example can be found [here](https://totallyinformation.github.io/nr-qa/dashboard-template-examples) but basically something like this:

```
<script>
    //console.dir(scope) // this also works
    //console.dir(scope.msg) // This doesn't because scope.msg doesn't yet exist

    // Lambda function to access the Angular Scope
    ;(function(scope) {
        //console.log('--- SCOPE ---')
        //console.dir(scope) // this works but you only get it once (on startup)
        //console.dir(scope.msg) // Doesn't work for  because scope.msg doesn't yet exist

        //Have to use $watch so we pick up new, incoming msg's
        scope.$watch('msg.payload', function(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log('- Scope.msg -')
            console.dir(scope.msg)
        })

    })(scope)
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks you, but where the msg.payload is now stored ? in scope.msg ?