# node-red - how to use a msg.payload within javascript in a template node (NOT ui-template)

Tags: javascript, html, node-red

I am trying to create a custom dashboard and have been able to configure it all using template nodes with my html, css, and javascript. My only challenge is that I have values being read using my a modbus flex getter node that are then passed through a function node and then into my template node with my javascript code.

I have found solutions for using msg.payload just within the html page, or using msg.payload within javascript but specifically referencing for the ui_template node, not the template node. I'll paste below the format of the solution for the ui_template node:

```
(function(scope){
     scope.$watch('msg',function(){
          ...
   })
})(scope)
```

I copied a few examples from the sources below and wasn't able to get any output in a template dashboard or the ui_template node-red dashboard, so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Source: https://flows.nodered.org/flow/2f1aaf0635f9bf23207152682323240a
source: [run javascript function using msg.payload in node-red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60491599/run-javascript-function-using-msg-payload-in-node-red)

Here is a simplified snippet of the code I wrote, and my node flow.

```
<script>

        const gaugeElement = document.querySelector(".gauge");
        
        (function(scope){
            scope.$watch('msg',function(){
                setGaugeValue(gaugeElement, 'msg', -5, 5);
        })
        })(scope)

        function setGaugeValue(gauge, value, min, max) {

            if (value > 0) {

            gauge.querySelector(".gauge-fill").style.transform = `rotate(${(((value / (max - min)) / 2) + 0.25)
                            }turn)`;

            gauge.querySelector(".gauge-cover").textContent = `${
                                (value)
                            } `;

            gauge.querySelector(".gauge-range-label").textContent =
                    `${Math.round((min))}` +'\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 ` + `${Math.round((max))}`;


            gauge.querySelector(".gauge-right-cover").style.visibility = "hidden";
            gauge.querySelector(".gauge-left-cover").style.visibility = "visible";

                        }
                    }
                    
    </script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

The follow is an example of to do this with the template node (note, NOT the dashboard-ui template node).

Template node content:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
This is the payload: {{payload}} !
        </p>
        <div id="foo">
        </div>
        <script type="application/javascript">
            var foo = JSON.parse('{{{payload}}}')
            console.log(foo)
        </script
    </body>
</html>
```

This first converts the `msg.payload` object to a JSON string then uses the tripple brace `{{{}}}` mustache template to stop the values being HTML escaped, and finally uses `JSON.parse()` to turn the JSON back into an object that can be used in the `<script>` tag.

```
[
    {
        "id": "69d9f34a07782a68",
        "type": "http in",
        "z": "5cf108a02a3da4ba",
        "name": "",
        "url": "/object",
        "method": "get",
        "upload": false,
        "swaggerDoc": "",
        "x": 210,
        "y": 340,
        "wires": [
            [
                "e18ba55b0be2f132"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0a5cbb817a984dc1",
        "type": "http response",
        "z": "5cf108a02a3da4ba",
        "name": "",
        "statusCode": "",
        "headers": {},
        "x": 850,
        "y": 340,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "526a543b58c781b9",
        "type": "template",
        "z": "5cf108a02a3da4ba",
        "name": "",
        "field": "payload",
        "fieldType": "msg",
        "format": "html",
        "syntax": "mustache",
        "template": "<html>\n    <head>\n        <title>Example</title>\n    </head>\n    <body>\n        <p>\nThis is the payload: {{payload}} !\n        </p>\n        <div id=\"foo\">\n        </div>\n        <script type=\"application/javascript\">\n            var foo = JSON.parse('{{{payload}}}')\n            console.log(foo)\n        </script\n    </body>\n</html>",
        "output": "str",
        "x": 700,
        "y": 340,
        "wires": [
            [
                "0a5cbb817a984dc1"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "e18ba55b0be2f132",
        "type": "change",
        "z": "5cf108a02a3da4ba",
        "name": "",
        "rules": [
            {
                "t": "set",
                "p": "payload",
                "pt": "msg",
                "to": "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}",
                "tot": "json"
            }
        ],
        "action": "",
        "property": "",
        "from": "",
        "to": "",
        "reg": false,
        "x": 380,
        "y": 340,
        "wires": [
            [
                "af74640d5c7d2f1d"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "af74640d5c7d2f1d",
        "type": "json",
        "z": "5cf108a02a3da4ba",
        "name": "",
        "property": "payload",
        "action": "",
        "pretty": false,
        "x": 550,
        "y": 340,
        "wires": [
            [
                "526a543b58c781b9"
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you!! Could this work with an input? I have an inject node connected to a modbus node going into the flow. I haven't been able to get those values to connect yet.

Comment: No, because the template node is rendered once when the page is sent to the browser, it has no access to the backend. The template-ui node is dynamic, the template node is not. You can use something like a websocket node to push data into a page generated from a template.